# How do I create a distinct count of every duplicate values in Cognos Report Studio?

Tags: sql, cognos-10

These are my current data

```
ACCOUNT NUMBER     PRODUCT          STATUS   RANK   DESIGN

    1  530033   Wealth Services     Closed    1     Manual
    2  530033   Wealth Services     Closed    2     Manual
    3  530033   Wealth Services     Closed    3     Manual
    4  530033   Wealth Services     Closed    4     Manual
    5  534656   Initial Escrow      Open      1     Manual
    6  534656   Initial Escrow      Open      2     Manual
    7  535161   Markets Integrity   Closed    1     Manual
    8  538379   Prepaid Cards       Closed    1     Manual
    9  538379   Prepaid Cards       Closed    2     Manual
    10 538379   Prepaid Cards       Closed    3     Manual
    11 538379   Prepaid Cards       Closed    4     Manual
    12 538915   Uploaded Cards      Open      1     Manual
    13 538915   Uploaded Cards      Open      2     Manual
    14 538915   Uploaded Cards      Open      3     Manual
```

I would like to create a column that would uniquely count every duplicate ACCOUNT NUMBER. For example Account number 530033 appeared four times, I would like to count every 530033 as one, same with the other account number 534656 appeared twice is till be counted as one.

I've already tried the following but none of these work.

```
count(distinct(Account Number))
count(distinct(Account Number) for Account Number)
```

with Aggregate columns equals to TOTAL, COUNT or AUTOMATIC.

I will use the data to create a cross-tab. My cross-tab gives me a a TOTAL count of 14 because it counts all duplicate account numbers. Because all account number have fourteen rows. But in reality there's only 5 account numbers (530033, 534656, 535161, 538379 and 53891)

```
                     TOTAL    Open         Closed
Wealth Services        4                       4
Initial Escrow         2         2
Markets Integrity      1                       1
Prepaid Cards          4                       4
Uploaded Cards         3         3
    TOTAL              14
```

Ideally it should be like this.

```
                    TOTAL    Open         Closed
Wealth Services        1                       1
Initial Escrow         1         1
Markets Integrity      1                       1
Prepaid Cards          1                       1
Uploaded Cards         1         1
    TOTAL              5
```

Should I create a new column named Unique count of account numbers? but how do I count the account number individually?

Do I have to create another table with unique account numbers then inner join both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the expressions you need are the following:

**TOTAL**

```
COUNT(DISTINCT [ACCOUNT NUMBER] for [PRODUCT])
```

**Open**

```
CASE [STATUS] 
WHEN 'Open' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT [ACCOUNT NUMBER] for [PRODUCT],[STATUS]) 
ELSE NULL  
END
```

**Closed**

```
CASE [STATUS] 
WHEN 'Closed' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT [ACCOUNT NUMBER] for [PRODUCT],[STATUS]) 
ELSE NULL 
END
```

Make sure you set the Aggregate Function for each data item to 'Calculated' since we are manually specifying the aggregate and rollup.

Comment: Hello Johnsonium. I used the logic you provided and created and it works! Thanks again.